# How can I prevent muscles from becoming tight?

Tags: muscle

How can I prevent muscles from becoming tight?

I am mostly interested in forearm muscles. My goal in preventing muscles tightness is to avoid perturbing the tendons that attach to the epicondyles at the elbow end of the humerus.